# Should I close unwraped OracleConnection in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I've got the following error in my application:
"DBCP object created by the following code was never closed".
After investigating the stacktrace I found there following lines:

```
OracleConnection oconn = null;

try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
    oconn = con.uwrap(OracleConnection.class);

    //........
} catch (Exception e) {
    //........
} finally {
    if (oconn != null && !oconn.isClosed()) {
        oconn.close();
    }
}
```

Could this code cause the error? How to handle uwrap connection? Should I close it? If yes, when - after closing of pool connection or after?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OracleConnection but I would look at that class and check our the close method.  It might call close on anything it is wrapping or it might not.

Comment: It probably needs to be closed before the `Connection.` I would add it to the resources block of the try-with-resources, but I would also ask why you need the `OracleConnection` at all.

Comment: I need OracleConnection for different purposes - for implementing DB change listeners, for setting specific oracle data types (OraclePreparedStatement)